# To what extent can the column generation method for solving linear programs be extended to solving more general convex optimization problems?

Tags: convex-optimization

Are there column generation approaches to solving classes of convex optimization problems other than LPs, and are they guaranteed to find a global minimizer?

Comment: Are you familiar with cutting plane methods? I've always found it hard to understand if the community distinguishes between the two.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I have some experience with cutting plane methods, but I hadn't recognized a connection with column generation algorithms. Can column generation for LPs be viewed as a cutting plane method?

Comment: I think they are very closely related, yes. With column generation, you are generating individual linear constraints programmatically. Aren't those cutting planes separating the feasible set from its complement?

Comment: I vaguely recall hearing of using column generation LP solvers to solve nonlinear convex problems.

Comment: "from its complement" that's not right. The columns generated / cutting planes separate the feasible set from an infeasible test point.

Answer (score 2):

Column generation is a standard tool for large scale, possibly smooth convex optimization problem.

Standard application are radiation therapy, traffic equilibrium among others.

Under suitable assumption column-generation scheme can also converge to critical point of non convex problems.

Take a look at

http://www.math.chalmers.se/~mipat/LATEX/CGSD.ps
http://oa.upm.es/15270/1/INVE_MEM_2011_122534.pdf